# How to downgrade from 64-bit to 32-bit

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, downgrade

I have a 2gb chromebook with 64-bit ubuntu 12.04 and it runs extremly slow and often crashes so how to I downgrade it to 32-bit or is their another solution?

Comment: It is unlikely that the downgrade solves the problem. Maybe you can elaborate what is the nature of the crashes so the community can help you. It is helpful to monitor the processes of the system. You can do that with "conky", "htop", "top", or the system monitor.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to convert an existing installation between 32-bit and 64-bit while keeping installed software. You need to do a reinstall.

The reason behind this is that it's actually classed as a different CPU architecture.  Despite the fact that the CPU can run either, and Linux distributions are starting to support multi-arch (and you can even run a 64-bit kernel with a 32-bit installation), you still need to choose one or the other for your base architecture and it's not something you can incrementally swap over on a working installation.

Note too that the assumption behind your question is false. If your computer is crashing on 64-bit it is almost certainly not because it is 64-bit. While there is always a possibility that a full reinstall (whether moving to different version/architecture or not) may solve a problem - particularly if you didn't have the problem when you first installed - it represents a last resort in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

You'd really need to completely reinstall, though if your /home resides on its own partition you could keep it.

I'd be doubtful it'd give much of a boost, especially since while 64 bit is a bit hungrier on memory, it's not that much hungrier and in some ways it's faster.

I'd try tweaking as per the various performance threads here, but on a low spec  machine I'd lean towards the lighter  desktop environments such as those that come with lubuntu  or  xubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

you have reinstall it, there's no way since the differentiation of architecture